# Добавление рекламной ссылки на сайт

Tags: javascript, html

Всем доброго времени суток! Друзья, помогите оформить ссылку на своем сайте. Ссылка такая:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://mwzona.com/gptr/go.php?b1=34209&type=pure>
</script>
```

В браузере в настройках  Java-вроде бы подключено, но ссылка не отображается. Может я что-то не так делаю, я еще пока что изучаю основы HTML и JavaScript. Может между тегами нужно что-то вставлять, ну, например, какой-нибудь текст, или еще что-то?

Эта ссылка на рекламу, за которую мне будут отчислятся маленькие процентики, но если я ссылку оформлю неправильно, то деньги вычтут с моего аккаунта. Может данную ссылку нужно как-то разместить между тегами `<noscript></noscript>`, если да, то как правильно это сделать? Во-первых по этой теме я еще совсем пряник, во-вторых хочу научится работать с JavaScript-ом и HTML-ем и мне кажется, у вас на форуме я этому быстрее научусь. А книги там всякие, это все балда, во-первых длинно и заумно через-чур, не все же институты заканчивали, а в школе, когда я учился, вообще про подобное думать не знали. Во-вторых, не совсем понятно, о чем именно хотят объяснить. Помогите, пожалуйста. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://mwzona.com/gptr/go.php?b1=34209&type=pure>
</script>
```

То, что вы написали, не ссылка, и отображаться не должно. Это тег javascript, который загружает содержимое указанное в src="" и запускает в окне у пользователя вашего сайта. Его исполнение может навредить вашей странице, так как вы не знаете, что он делает, по URL не хожу :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://mwzona.com/gptr/go.php?b1=34209&type=pure">
</script>
```

Comment: type забыли. type="text/javascript", браузеры могут ругаться на несовпадение типа.